# How to know through storefront website of Salesforce Commerce Cloud where Einstein is configured and providing results or not?

Tags: search, commerce-cloud

Through Salesforce Commerce Cloud Storefront websites, i would like to know whether particular websites running showing more results where Einstein is configured and providing results or not?

Can anyone briefly knows any steps?

- Any DOM elements render by Einstein search if it configured If yes where can I find it?
- Based on single search terms("shoes", "shirts") or multiple search terms like "shoes under 100"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a browser plugin available for this (Chrome):

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/commerce-cloud-recommenda/dobmbolmcejainkefklnpkjbaibgjihn

Though this allows you to verify if you configured your site correctly, you can check others.